# How can I get my array from the use-effect react hook to be made available in my render method

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component

How come when I log to the console my array from inside of use-effect, it is working but when I try to render it, or log it to the console outside the use-effect set, it is not.
My colleges array is not rendering nor is it logging to the console.log once it is set with the setColleges(colleges) function

```
   const [colleges, setColleges] = useState([]);

 function PlayerProfiles(props) {
   const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/players',
        params: {team: '1', season: '2021'},
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
    };
     useEffect(() => {
   axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
       var collegesArray = []
        var reply = response;
        var postData = response.data.response.map(a => a.firstname + a.lastname)
        var count = 0;
        var schools = response.data.response.map(a => {
            var collegesArray = []
            try {
                var colleges = response.data.response[++count].college
                collegesArray.push(colleges)
              //  console.log('here are the colleges' + collegesArray)
                setColleges(collegesArray)
              //  console.log(colleges)  <---------- This is showing up
        }catch (error) {}

        })

        return axios.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3502/nameslist',
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            data: {namesList: postData},
            newNamesArray: []
        }).then(
            function (response) {
               console.log(colleges)
                return axios.get('http://localhost:3502/pictures',
                    {
                        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                        withCredentials: true,
                    }).then(function (response) {
                    var cnt = 0;
                    var newcnt = 0;
                    return reply.data.response.map(a => {
                        var newNamesArray = []
                        try {
                            var newNames = response.data[++newcnt].search_parameters.q
                            newNamesArray.push(newNames)
                            // console.log(newNames + "are the new names")
                            var imgurl = response.data[++cnt].images_results[0].thumbnail
                            var imgurlArray = []
                            imgurlArray.push(imgurl)
                            Array.prototype.push.apply(newNamesArray, imgurlArray)
                        } catch (error) {}
                       console.log(newNamesArray)
                       // console.log(collegesArray)
                        return newNamesArray
                    })

                })
            })


    }).then(playerData => setEverything(playerData)).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    })
     },[]);
console.log(colleges) <---------- This is NOT showing up
   return (all my jsx )
```

Comment: Store the array in the state.

Comment: The use-effect (react-hooks) is the state. Can you provide an example? @NiceBooks

Comment: Your `useState` is outside the `PlayersProfile` component. Why ? It should be inside a component or a hook.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the setColleges hook function is stuck in the map function. It needs to be set outside of it for it to work correctly.